# Wiring real dependencies into Spring Boot integration test

Tags: spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

Spring Boot integration testing here. I have the following service class:

```
@Service
public class PasswordService implements PasswordEncoder {

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator;
    private CharacterCharacteristicsRule passwordCharacteristicsRule;
    private Integer minPasswordLength;

    @Autowired
    public PasswordService(
            BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator,
            CharacterCharacteristicsRule passwordCharacteristicsRule,
            @Value("${myapp.users.passwords.min-length}") Integer minPasswordLength) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.passwordGenerator = passwordGenerator;
        this.passwordCharacteristicsRule = passwordCharacteristicsRule;
        this.minPasswordLength = minPasswordLength;
    }

    public String generatePassword() {
        return passwordGenerator.generatePassword(minPasswordLength, passwordCharacteristicsRule.getRules());
    }

    public String protectPassword(String plaintextPassword) {
        return passwordEncoder.encode(plaintextPassword);
    }

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
        return protectPassword(rawPassword.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        return protectPassword(rawPassword.toString()).equals(encodedPassword);
    }

}
```

I have a unit test for each method, but because its `generatePassword()` method is so important and depends so heavily on its dependencies, I also want to create an integration test for it that actually autowires/injects it with **real** instances of all of its dependencies.

My best attempt:

```
public class PasswordServiceIT {

    @Inject
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Inject
    private PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator;

    @Inject
    private CharacterCharacteristicsRule passwordCharacteristicsRule;

    private PasswordService passwordService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        passwordService = new PasswordService(passwordEncoder, passwordGenerator, passwordCharacteristicsRule, 10);
    }

    @Test
    public void when_generatePassword_should_generate_valid_password() {

        String password = passwordService.generatePassword();
        System.out.println(String.format("Password is: %s", password));

    }


}
```

Throws NPEs because `passwordEncoder` and `passwordGenerator` are being injected as `null`. Again I'm looking for the **real** `BCryptPasswordEncoder` and the **real** `PasswordGenerator` and the **real** `CharacterCharacteristicsRule` to be injected into my `PasswordService` instance here, so I can take it for a **real** test spin.

Can anybody spot where I'm going awry here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your Junit version?

Comment: I'm using `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2` but can upgrade if need be. FWIW I'm on Spring Boot 2.6.3 as well -- thanks!

Comment: you have to use `@SpringBootTest` annotation, read this doc https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#integration-testing-with-springboottest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create an instance for your service `PasswordService` using the `new` keyword. If you do, all the `@Inject`/`@Autowire` members will be null. You need to inject the `PassworService` also.

And annotate the test class with `org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest` so when running the tests, a spring context will be created.

So you test class will as follows.

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class PasswordServiceIT {

    @Inject
    private PasswordService passwordService;

    @Test
    public void when_generatePassword_should_generate_valid_password() {
        String password = passwordService.generatePassword();
        System.out.println(String.format("Password is: %s", password));
    }
}
```

You don't need to inject other classes unless you directly use it in your tests in this class.

Note: For this, you need `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` should be in the test scope dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) @SpringBootTest to your class. I think spring does not see your injecting, so it might help.

And you can replace all your injects by

```
 @Autowired
 private PasswordService passwordService;
```